# How do I remove the rest of this Moen faucet handle?

Tags: faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I don't know the exact Moen model number of this bathroom facuet, but I need to replace the cartridge below one handle to stop a slow leak its causing from the tap.  I've removed the little cap on top and the screw it hides inside, which allows me to take the lever off, but I see no way to remove the rest of that side of the faucet.

[image: Faucet with right handle removed]

All the videos I've seen explaining how to do this note that the part of the faucet protecting the cartridge should just lift off now, or screw off, but mine doesn't want to budge at all.  Am I missing something else that is securing it on the body of the faucet?  Here's a photo of the entire faucet for reference:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a strap wrench or leather belt and turning that piece counterclockwise?

Comment: I think Jack has it spot on... guessing there are a couple threads on the bottom of that "bell like housing" Don't get too overzealous with it, but it should be "easy" to turn with a good grip. Don't apply pliers or tools without something inbetween it to avoid scratching/denting/scraping

Comment: @JACK - that was it!  I had never heard of a strap wrench before.  I tried my leather belt first but couldn't get a good grip on it.  Earlier, I had tried a rubber grip pad, but the piece wouldn't budge.  So, before spending money on a new tool, I tried the rubber pad again, assuming that I just needed more grip and force, and eventually it yielded to me.  If you put your comment into an answer, I'll mark it as my solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @Derek Glad it worked out.  Strap wrenches are really cheap. I bought my first one to replace an aerator on a faucet and have since then used it on many different occasions for all sorts of stuff.

Comment: I had the same problem with a similar Moen faucet, although in my case the "bell" housing was more curved, and more difficult to get a grip on. Nylon strap wrench didn't work. Eventually I tried putting foam weather strip tape around the housing, and then used the strap wrench, and it worked. Just needed to get a good grip. The strap wrench was also useful for removing the locking nut (didn't need any extra grip for that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a strap wrench or leather belt and turning that piece counterclockwise?

I've had good luck with both.

Comment: That did the trick - I just needed to get a better grip on the bottom piece and turn it with more force.

Answer (score 1):

As @ Jack said, those next bell shaped pieces turn off, either by hand or with a strap wrench. By the way, make sure that you call the MOEN factory for help and advice. Many times those replacement parts are guaranteed for life and are free. My faucets are 22 years old and I always get free replacement parts. One time, since the faucets were no longer made and parts were no longer available, they sent me new free complete faucets. My 2 cents.

Comment: I had a plumber say the same thing about my Moen kitchen faucet.  The finish is starting to wear away, and he said that they'll likely replace the entire thing because of their warranty.